# Does GHC compare pointers before invoking Eq?

Tags: haskell, comparison

[This entry on the mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2014-August/115668.html) from 2014 seems to indicate that the answer is no. If it's still no, how can I quickly compare two giant data structures where one is either an exact match of the other, or a slightly changed version?

Comment: Why would GHC compare pointers before invoking Eq? If you want fast equality checks of giant data structures, why not use a Merkle tree or similar?

Comment: You can also (although this i a terribly bad idea), define `_ == _ = False` (so everything is `False`), by comparing pointers, it would be `True`.

Comment: Furthermore one of the concepts behind Haskell is usually that you do not know about pointers (yes Haskell code gives a good idea how it works with pointers behind the curtains, but conceptually, it is unknown how the compiler translates this).

Comment: @Rein because if the pointers are equal, the contents are equal.

Comment: @FilipHaglund There's actually no law that says that `x == x = True`.

Comment: Well, there could be one for Eq. If you want a non-reflexive equality you could define your own. In most cases, it's reflexive, and then this would be a performance optimization, and quite a big one for larger structures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. `Eq` is a typeclass like any other, so `x == x` (the reflexive law) is a user-enforced guideline - not a compiler enforced one. As suggested in the comments, you could implement the following instance of `Eq` for which comparing pointers would actually be incorrect (since doing so might sometimes return `True`).

```
data NeverEqual = NeverEqual

instance Eq NeverEqual where
  _ == _ = False
```

#### Unsafe stuff, please don't use this - but yes, it exists:

That said, there are some *very limited* cases where one actually does want to do what you suggest. You can pretty much always eke out performance elsewhere instead, and this function I am about to mention is going to break referential transparency.

For those cases, there is the [`reallyUnsafePtrEquality# :: a -> a -> Int#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.1.1/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:reallyUnsafePtrEquality-35-) which compares the pointers of two boxed values of the same type returning `1#` when they are equal and `0#` otherwise. See [`unordered-containers`](https://github.com/tibbe/unordered-containers/blob/c0d3976fbc96d566ae3fc457b670a6618dae8a8d/Data/HashMap/Base.hs#L1348) and [`containers`](https://github.com/haskell/containers/blob/71e293eb0849dee89dbabc6bd7fa258094b4db6c/Utils/Containers/Internal/PtrEquality.hs#L34-L38) for example uses.

Comment: `containers` does use this, and has for a couple years. Where does `unordered-containers` use it?

Comment: I don't think the use cases for `reallyUnsafePtrEquality` are "very limited" - I think you could use it in very many places where you want to improve the performance of equality checks. So long as you understand the caveats about false negatives; however, it will never give a false positive, so it's pretty safe. Also from what I can tell the GHC docs are wrong; it returns `#1` for equal and `#0` for not equal

Comment: @user2407038 Indeed. Good catch on the error; [I've filed a bug report](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14653) concerning the bad documentation

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks! I had recently surveyed the  open tickets of `containers` and [this](https://github.com/haskell/containers/issues/226) misled me. :)

Comment: @user2407038 I maintain that there is almost always lower hanging fruit. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens when I forget to close tickets, or forget they exist. Thanks for the tip. And you just made me realize that my next experiment will be using unboxed sums for unions and intersections rather than pointer equality. Can I put everything I want on the GHC stack? Maybe I can now.